# single image to multiple image upload

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I have the follow script that uploads and image and a thumbnail to a directory and store the img names (img and thumb) to the database.

I originally found this script somewhere on the web while googling but, but now I need to be able to upload more than one image... it works fine for one image as is.

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";


 define ("MAX_SIZE","400");
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {

            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=60;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


$newwidth1=25;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);


$filename = "images/". $_FILES['file']['name'];

$filename1 = "images/small". $_FILES['file']['name'];



imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}}

}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `imgs` (`id` ,`user_id` ,`img_name`) VALUES (NULL ,  '$userID',  'img1.jpg');");
    $change=' <div class="msgdiv">Image Uploaded Successfully!</div>';
 }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
  </head><body>
<?php echo $change; ?> 

              <div id="posts">
              <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
              <input size="25" name="file" type="file" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt" class="box"/>
              <input type="submit" id="mybut" value="Upload" name="Submit"/>
              </form>
              </div>
</body></html>
```

for multiple image I know I can change the html portion to a foreach loop, like:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
            <?php
$allow_upload = 10; 
for($i=0; $i<$allow_upload; $i++) { 
            echo '<input size="25" name="file[]" type="file" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt" class="box"/>'; 
        }
?>          
<input type="submit" id="mybut" value="Upload" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

but I havent been able to figure how and where to put a foreach loop and and adapty the rest for multiple images.

my db setup would be something like id, userID, big img, small img.
any help would be greatly appreciated, im ready to start pulling my hair out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to loop multiple file input elements then you need to tell that it is an array unless you have a different name for each input elements.

```
for($i=0; $i<$allow_upload; $i++) { 
    echo '<input size="25" name="file[]" type="file"'/>; 
}
```

if you want to select multiple file from one input element then

```
<input name="filesToUpload[]" type="file" multiple/>
```

Comment: sorry, I meant to do name="file[]", that much I do understand.

Comment: if you understand the array then `$_FILES` will have all the values. you can try `var_dump($_FILES)` to check the content in your PHP script and then loop it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple input files you can use a single input file and save all the files in array, and use foreach to save each file to folder.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


foreach($_FILES['allimages'] as $files) {
var_dump($files);
    }
}

?>

<form id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="allimages[]" id="allimages" multiple><!--Use CTRL key to upload multiple images -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

you need to hold cntrl key to upload multiple files.